# Flow loop collection - can it be a decision as to which collection to run loop on?

Tags: visual-workflow, loop

Background:
Flow as Lead Router(aka Round Robin) by Program
Rules have members (users) who may be active or inactive (think out of office, not user account)
If a program is matched to a rule but there are no active members, then use default rule and related members.

My flow assigns the rule members to a collection A, then filters to only active rule members collection B.
If there are no active members in this filtered collection B, I need to loop through the default rule active member collection rather than collection B.

I need a way to tell the loop to run on whichever collection needs to be used.  Please see image.

[image: Lead Router Flow screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Add a Collection variable, which we'll call PossibleMembers. Now, filter for the active members, and add those results to PossibleMembers. If PossibleMembers is empty, then get the default rule and members, and add those to PossibleMembers. Finally, loop over PossibleMembers, rather than trying to select from two different Collections.

Comment: I understand what you are saying, however I can not figure out how to take records from two collections and assign them to a new PossibleMembers collection.

Comment: @Suzie Use the Assignment element to copy the values from either collection to the PossibleMembers collection.

Comment: I figured it out about the same time you posted! Thanks for your help.